# RequireJS error handling

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs

I am adding jquery using requireJS like

```
requirejs.config({
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
        jquery: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min'
    }
});
```

Later in seperate JS file I am loading on page using require as

```
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    //Do something with $ here
}, function (err) {});
```

I gave jquery URL incorrectly and want to show some custom err message to end user..I added above code but when URL is incorrect the control is not coming inside err function..Do I want to add any other code..I am using for DOJO version.

Comment: Your last line confused me. Are you using the Dojo AMD loader or RequireJS? They have different error handling, so if you're using Dojo, it won't work as described in your question. Print the following in your console: `define.amd`, what does it say?

Comment: It is returing Object { vendor="dojotoolkit.org"}

Comment: That means you're not using RequireJS, but you're using the Dojo AMD loader.

Comment: I am using Dojo AMD loader only..It worked fine..Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're using the Dojo AMD loader, they have a different approach of handling errors.

While in RequireJS you would use:

```js
require([ 'jquery' ], function($) {
  // Do something with $ here
}, function(err) {
  // Error handling
});
```

In Dojo you would use a different syntax, for example:

```js
require.on('error', function(err) {
  // Error handling
});
require([ 'jquery' ], function($) {
  // Do something with $ here
});
```

An example: http://plnkr.co/edit/t3j7mTgLKSiTCIrvl2eD?p=preview

However, since you're using Dojo, the `requirejs.config()` does probably not work either if you're working the Dojo AMD loader.